# Change color of line in line plot

Tags: python, pandas

I have a plot that has two lines - I would like to change the color of both lines to something than what it currently is. My code below changes both lines to red and when I try to change the colors portion of the code to `color=('red', 'blue')`, I get the following error

> ValueError: RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4

Do you know how I can fix my code so I can set my first line to red and my second line to blue?

```
g3.plot(SZ_ED_TOT['Week'], SZ_ED_TOT['ESI_1_2_3'],SZ_ED_TOT['ESI_4_5'],color=('red'))
g3.set_title('SZ Acuity Count')
g3.tick_params(labelrotation=45)
g3.set_ylabel('Patient Count')
g3.set_xlabel('Week')
g3.legend(['ESI_1_2_3', 'ESI_4_5'],
          loc='upper right', frameon=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g3.plot(SZ_ED_TOT['Week'], SZ_ED_TOT['ESI_1_2_3'], color='blue')
g3.plot(SZ_ED_TOT['Week'], SZ_ED_TOT['ESI_4_5'], color='red')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.gca().set_color_cycle(['blue', 'green'])

plt.plot(SZ_ED_TOT['Week'], SZ_ED_TOT['ESI_1_2_3'])

plt.plot(Z_ED_TOT['Week'], SZ_ED_TOT['ESI_4_5'])
```